# Passing info typed by user into View and creating a new widget-like card with it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

In the process of making my first personal finance tracker, but I'm stuck since I want to create a new card like the ones appearing under "Your cards" with the information the user typed after pressing "Add new".

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var wallet: Wallet

@State var isPresentingAddModal = false

@State var cardType = ""
@State var cardNumber = ""
    
var headerView: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Your cards")
            .font(.title2)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
        Spacer()
        Button("Add new") {
            self.isPresentingAddModal.toggle()
            print("Trying to add new card")}

            .font(.callout)
            .foregroundColor(Color.primaryPurple)
            .padding(.trailing)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingAddModal, content: {
        
        HStack (spacing: 16) {
            Text("Card type")
            TextField("Enter your card type", text: $cardType)
        }
        
        HStack (spacing: 16) {
            Text("Card Number")
            TextField("Enter your card number", text: $cardNumber)
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            self.isPresentingAddModal.toggle()
            print("\(self.cardType)" + " " + "\(self.cardNumber)")
            
            // Code needed to be able to pass user info into the Wallet Cards...
            
        }, label: {
            Text("Add")
                .padding(.all, 16)
        })
        Spacer()
    })

    }
    
  //Creating the Cards index...

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        headerView
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(wallet.cards.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    CardView(card: wallet.cards[index])
                        .onTapGesture {
                            wallet.cards.indices.forEach { index in
                                wallet.cards[index].isSelected = false
                            }
                            wallet.cards[index].isSelected.toggle()
                        }
                   }
              }
         }
    }
}
}
```

The Modal that appears after clicking "Add new" is super basic, but I'm trying to make it functional first.

[image: The Home view]

Comment: What is your issue? You haven't asked a question? Are you asking somebody to write the code for you? If so, this is not the place for that

Comment: No, there's no issue with the code. I'm asking how to pass that info to create another Card with it. But since this is very specific, I couldn't find anything on the web that addresses this specifically.

Comment: In theory and if you code works you should just add the new card in that `Button` action to `wallet.cards`. Once the `.sheet` is dismissed the array will already have the card and be showing it.

Comment: Yup, added 'wallet.cards.append' and then 'init' for all the info required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `wallet.cards.append(Card.init())` creates another card on the index, with the information passed by user.

Inside the parenthesis of `init` it should go all **constants/variables** wanted.

Simple, but can save someone's time, and future headaches!